# Running executable in Xcode requires Info.plist but it running fine from terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, info.plist

The executable is compiled from Xcode successfully, but it failed with this error:

> [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

But the executable can successfully run from the terminal on the same MacBook Pro system.

I also tried to create the info.plist with NSCameraUsageDescription key and set "Create Info.plist Section in Binary" to Yes in setting. But it failed with the same error.

What should I do in order to run the application inside Xcode?

The OS is macOS10.14.3, Xcode is version 10.1.

Comment: Run from the terminal? How? Is it an app or a command line tool?

Comment: It is command line tool.

Comment: NSCameraUsageDescription - Does it have value of String? Have you checked details of compiled app (info.plist) after Xcode compiled the app (show package content)?

Comment: Yes, the value is string. I can see the info.plist section in executable file. And after I delete the info.plist file, compile the executable, I don't see the info.plist section in it, but it runs successfully from terminal. It seems that OS doesn't requires the info.plist section, but Xcode does, and it can't find it when it is in the binary file.
The executable file is Unix Executable type, there is no show package content option, but I view it in hex editor.

Comment: Have you given Xcode itself permission to use the camera? This is Mojave, you have to do that in System Preferences.

Comment: Try to look here + how author solved command line application https://github.com/matthutchinson/videosnap/issues/15

Comment: Thanks, Matt! I can't give Xcode permission to Camera from System Preference since there is no '+' sign on the window. According to this article (https://www.howtogeek.com/361707/how-macos-mojaves-privacy-protection-works/) "You can’t give an app access to this data if it doesn’t ask for it". Do you know how to give Xcode permission to access Camera.

Comment: Matt's comment explained why the command line tool can access Camera with info.plist since it is executed by terminal.
Follow that path and this article [link](https://jtdaugh.github.io/xcode-umich/), I can edit the scheme to use terminal to run the application in Xcode.
Although I still want to know how to run the command line tool directly in Xcode with access to Camera.